# Having a completely different Form when pressing the update score Button

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a program that uses multiple Forms.

When I go press the update score Button I get a completely different Form called the score in its place. 
However, once I input the name and the score the update `score` Form appears after pressing ok.

Is there any way to get just the update `score` Form as its stand-alone Form without having to go through the `score` Form?

Update `score` Form:

```
public UppDateScore()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    score link = new score();
    DialogResult bUpdate = link.ShowDialog();

    if (bUpdate == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtName.Text = link.tagName.ToString();
        numberBox.Items.Add((string)link.Tagnumbers);
        //TagNumbs2
        numberBox.Items.Add((string)link.TagNumbs2);
        // TagNumbers3
        numberBox.Items.Add((string)link.TagNumbers3);
    }
}
```

Original Form:

```
private void bUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UppDateScore update = new UppDateScore();
    update.Show();
}
```

`score` Form:

```
private void bClearScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtName.Text = "";
     txtScore.Text = "";
     txtStoreScores.Text = "";
}

private void bOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string name = txtName.Text;
     int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
     int amount = list[0]+ list[1]+list[2];
     string test = null;
     test = amount.ToString();
     string msg = null;
     msg = name;

     //just get the name
     string theName = null;
     theName = name;

     // just get the numbers you typed in
     // first number
     string aNumber = null;
     int theNumbers1 = list[0];
     aNumber = theNumbers1.ToString();

     // sencend number
     string theNumber2 = null;
     int theNumbers2 = list[1];
     theNumber2 = theNumbers2.ToString();

     // third number
     string theNumber3 = null;
     int theNumbers3 = list[2];
     theNumber3 = theNumbers3.ToString();

     // get the amount in the list
     string amountSize = null;
     int scoreSize = list.Count;
     amountSize = scoreSize.ToString();

     // get the avarage
     int avarge = amount / scoreSize;
     string theAvarge = null;
     theAvarge = avarge.ToString();
     foreach (int s  in list) {

     msg += " | " + s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please try to make your post more clear :) What is the problem *exactly*? Are there any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Is it better to understand now ??

Comment: `new` does what the word implies - it creates a ***new*** form instance.  If that is not what you want then hold onto the previous one

Comment: @Super_Fly: basically, your question's answer is in the `bUpdate_Click` code block. Take that code, and put it where you want the form to show up.